# which jquery i can use?

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery

hey guys i want to create one display form in which at the bottom images with some text are display in a sliding format.
And when user take mouse pointer onto image that time at the top that image look bigger compare to bottom image.& with image some text also appear with "readmore" button.
when you click "readmore" then it redirect to other page which have full info about selected content.
for clear view what i said visit www.yahoo.com

i want to create some like that for displaying news with pics.

Comment: yahoo is using the YUI library. But you should do fine with jQuery 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pratickg88:  This is what I used in a similar project:

[jCarousel](http://thomlx.free.fr/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm) combined with [jQuery 1.4.2](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/02/19/jquery-142-released/).

Then I did something rolling my own Carousel class in another project:

http://www.phpexperts.pro/demos/graph_sort/

[JavaScript source code](http://www.phpexperts.pro/demos/graph_sort/js/graph_sort.js) for that widget.